# Need help finding the perimeter of this shape

Tags: geometry, education

I need help finding the perimeter of this shape. I know how to get the perimeter of these shapes individually  but together I am at a loss. Help is appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7WU1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one side of an equilateral triangle plus five-sixths of the circumference of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the lines across the sides of the triangle mean it is equilateral so the angle of the arc is $\pi/3$

So with $r$ being the radius the circumference is $2\pi r$, the length of the missing arc is $\pi r/3$ and the length of the chord is $r$

The perimeter is therefore

$$2\pi r-{\pi r\over 3}+r=\left({5\pi\over 3}+1\right)r$$